# how to determine that the created index is dense or sparse in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created an index in MySQL workbench using this syntax:

```
create index ixdex_name on table_name (id asc);
```

but i want to know that whether this created index is dense or sparse, so please tell how can I determine that?

Answer (score 3):

The mysql indexes are dense indexes.

**Dense Indexes:**
A dense index in database is a file with pairs of keys and pointers for every record in the data file. Every key in this file is associated with a particular pointer to a record in the sorted data file.
which is the normal way of storage in the mysql databases.

source:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Dense_index

Answer (score 2):

MySQL indexes are dense. I have not heard this discussed in the context of MySQL before, is this for a class or a real life application?